# postgres query to return some of column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I've the following query which return the run time for 1200 videos , i want to get the total of run time in  `hh:mm:ss:ms`

```
select  runtime from video where ready_date between '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30';
```

my output will look like

```
"00:00:33:07"

"00:00:37:09"

"00:01:52:02"

"00:00:41:05"
```

i've tried  sum(runtime) but looks i'm doing the wrong thing here ,

any tips ?

Comment: Please include the table definition.   Alternatively set up a test in http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way - cast it to timestamp then to time then to interval, then it will sum up ok, eg:

```
vao=# with video(runtime) as (values('00:00:33:07'),('00:00:37:09'),('00:01:52:02'))
select sum(to_timestamp(runtime,'HH24:MI:ss:ms')::time::interval) from video;
     sum
-------------
 00:03:02.18
(1 row)
```

*update*: In your case would be smth like:

```
select sum(to_timestamp(runtime::text,'HH24:MI:ss:ms')::time::interval) 
from video 
where ready_date between '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30';
```

Comment: i'll have to put 1200 values manully , can it join by select  statement like this  select  runtime from video where ready_date between '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-30';

Comment: Perfect , all i need :) Thank Vao